# Esky freezes after escalating permissions on windows 7

Tags: python, windows

We're about to start using [Esky](https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky) to deploy updates to our application. On Windows 7, Esky appears to be unable to get the escalated privileges it needs to install an update.

I've narrowed it down to this simple script. It asks for escalated permissions, but will either freeze, or crash with the stacktrace below.

### Script

```
import esky
import esky.sudo

class MyProgram(object):

    @esky.sudo.allow_from_sudo()
    def do_stuff(self):
        pass


app = MyProgram()

sapp = esky.sudo.SudoProxy(app)

sapp.start()
sapp.do_stuff()
sapp.drop_root()
```

### Stack Trace

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    sapp.start()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\esky\sudo\__init__.py", line 125, in start
    raise RuntimeError("sudo helper process terminated unexpectedly")
RuntimeError: sudo helper process terminated unexpectedly


$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    sapp.start()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\esky\sudo\__init__.py", line 140, in start
    self.close()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\esky\sudo\__init__.py", line 156, in close
    self.pipe.read()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\esky\sudo\sudo_base.py", line 123, in read
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Does anyone know of a solution, or have any suggestions?

Using:

- python 2.7.3
- esky 0.9.7

Answer (score 0):

3 years and no answer that is very sad :(

This is a bug in esky.

Esky works fine for me besides the fact that escalating privileges fails.

I'm used to programming in python3... so once I'm done updating Esky to be python 2 and 3 compatible I'm going to tackle this issue.

If anyone wants to solve this problem let's rock and roll! To the github issue tracker!

Answer (score -1):

This is super late, but if anyone in the future has this problem, try running `sudo python your_program.py`.

Comment: The program runs fine if the user already has admin privileges, the problem is in escalating them.